# Invariant Generics don't seem working correctly

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, diamond-operator, invariance

I've read some articles about *Covariance*, *Contravariance*, and *Invariance* in Java, but I'm confused about them.

I'm using Java 11, and I have a class hierarchy `A => B => C` (means that `C` is a subtype of `B` and `A`, and `B` is a subtype of `A`) and a class `Container`:

```
class Container<T> {
    public final T t;
    public Container(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
}
```

for example, if I define a function:

```
public Container<B> method(Container<B> param){
  ...
}
```

here is my confusion, why does the third line compile?

```
method(new Container<>(new A())); // ERROR
method(new Container<>(new B())); // OK
method(new Container<>(new C())); // OK Why ?, I make a correction, this compiles OK
```

if in Java Generics are *invariant*.

When I define something like this:

```
Container<B> conta =  new Container<>(new A()); // ERROR, Its OK!
Container<B> contb =  new Container<>(new B()); // OK, Its OK!
Container<B> contc =  new Container<>(new C()); // Ok, why ? It's not valid, because they are invariant
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the boons introduced with Java 7 is the so-called [*diamond operator*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond) `<>`.

And it has been with us for so long, that it's easy to forget that every time when diamond is being used while instantiating a generic class the compiler should **infer** the generic type from the context.

If we define a variable which will hold a reference to a list of `Person` objects like this:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>(); // effectively - ArrayList<Person>()
```

the compiler will *infer* the type of the `ArrayList` instance from the type of the variable `people` on the left.

In the *Java language specification*, the expression `new ArrayList<>()` is being described as a [*class instance creation expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9) and because it doesn't specify the generic type parameter and is used within a *context*, it should be classified as being a ***poly expression***. A quote from the specification:

> A *class instance creation expression* is a **poly expression** (§15.2) if
> it uses the **diamond** form for type arguments to the class, and it
> appears in an **assignment context** or an **invocation context** (§5.2,
> §5.3).

I.e. when *diamond* `<>` is used with a generic class instantiation, the actual type will depend on the **context** in which it appears.

The three statements below represent the case of so-called *assignment context*. And all three instances `Container` will be inferred as being of type `B`.

```
Container<B> conta = new Container<>(new A()); // 1 - ERROR   because `B t = new A()` is incorrect
Container<B> contb = new Container<>(new B()); // 2 - fine    because `B t = new B()` is correct
Container<B> contc = new Container<>(new C()); // 3 - fine    because `B t = new C()` is also correct
```

Since all instances of container are of type `B` and of parameter type expected by the contractor also will be `B`. I.e. can provide an instance of `B` or any of its subtypes. Therefore, in the case `1` we are getting a compilation error, meanwhile `2` and `3` (`B` and subtype of `B`) will compile correctly.

And it in't a violation of *invariant behavior*. Think about it this way: we can store in a `List<Number>` instances of `Integer`, `Byte`, `Double`, etc., that would not lead to any problem since they all can represent their super type `Number`. But the compiler will not allow assigning this list to any list that is not of type `List<Number>` because otherwise it would be impossible to ensure that this assignment is safe. And that is what the invariance means - we can assign only `List<Number>` to a variable of type `List<Number>` (but we are free to store any subtype of `Number` in it, it's safe).

As an example, let's consider that there's a setter method in the `Container` class:

```
public class Container<T> {
    public T t;
    public Container(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
        
    public void setT(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
}
```

Now let's use it:

```
Container<B> contb =  new Container<>(null); // to avoid any confusion initialy `t` will be assigned to `null`

contb.setT(new A()); // compilation error - because expected type is `B` or it's subtype
contb.setT(new B()); // fine
contb.setT(new C()); // fine because C is a subtype of B
```

When we deal with a class instance creation expression using diamond `<>`, which is passed to a method as an argument, the type will be inferred from the *invocation context* as the quote from the specification provided above states.

Because `method()` expects `Container<B>`, all instances above will be inferred as being of type `B`.

```
method(new Container<>(new A())); // Error
method(new Container<>(new B())); // OK - because `B t = new B()` is correct
method(new Container<>(new C())); // OK - because `B t = new C()` is also correct
```

***Note***

The important thing to mention that prior to Java 8 (*i.e. with Java 7, because we are using diamond*) the expression `new Container<>(new C())` will be interpreted by the compiler as a *standalone expression* (i.e. the context will be ignored) creating an instance of `Container<C>`. It means your initial guess was somewhat correct: with **Java 7** the below statement would not compile.

```
Container<B> contc = new Container<>(new C()); // Container<B> = Container<C> - is an illegal assignment
```

But Java 8 has introduced a feature called [*target types*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types) and *poly expressions* (i.e. expressions that appear within a *context*) that insures that *context* will always be taken into account by the type inference mechanism.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your comment, your explanation is more than clear, I appreciate the time you dedicated to my question.

Answer (score 4):

Covariance is the ability to pass or specify a subtype when a supertype is expected. If your C class extends B, then C is a child class of B. This relationship between C and B is also called `is-a` relationship, where an instance of C is also an instance of B. Therefore, when your variable `contc` is expecting an instance of B and you're passing `new C()`, since `new C()` is an instance of C and also `is-a` instance of B, then the compiler allows the following writing:

`Container<B> contc =  new Container<>(new C());`

Conversely, when you're writing

`Container<B> conta =  new Container<>(new A());`

you're receiving an error because A is a **supertype** of B, there is no `is-a` relationship from A to B, but rather from B to A. This is because every instance of B is also an instance of A, but not every instance of A is an instance of B. Making a silly example, every thumb is a finger but not every finger is a thumb. A is a generalization of B; therefore, an instance of A cannot appear where an instance of B is expected.

Here there's a good article expanding the concept of covariance in java.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-covariant-return-type

Answer (score 4):

The question's examples don't demonstrate the invariance of generics.

An example which does demonstrate this would be:

```
ArrayList<Object> ao = new ArrayList<String>(); // does not compile
```

(You might incorrectly expect the above to compile, because `String` is a subclass of `Object`.)

The question shows us different ways to construct `Container<B>` objects - some of which compile and others which do not, because of the inheritance hierarchy of `A`, `B` and `C`.

That diamond operator `<>` means that the created container is of type `B` in every case.

If you take the following example:

```
Container<B> contc =  new Container<>(new C()); // compiles
```

And re-write it by populating the diamond with `C`, the  you will see that the following does not compile:

```
Container<B> contc =  new Container<C>(new C()); // does not compile
```

That will give you the same "incompatible types" compilation error as my `ArrayList` example.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know how the diamond operator worked, it was a conceptual error on my part.  Now I understand why the code compiled, I appreciate your response andrewJames.
Thank you so much